# Tomcat web.xml url mapping

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Am new to J2ee. I have the following configured as my web.xml

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>TestGetServlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>src.java.com.testGet.TestGet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>TestGetServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/servlet/TestGet</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Java Code

```
package src.java.com.testGet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class TestGet extends HttpServlet {

    String WebPage = "<html><body> Hello World Again </body></html>";

    @Override
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("Servlet initialized");
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse responce){
        try{
            responce.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter aPW = responce.getWriter();
            aPW.println(WebPage);
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

But tomcat returns the following error

```
HTTP Status 404 - /TestGetServlet/servlet/TestGet
```

I have build the application with ant and it deployed ok, but it does not provide a way to automatically generate the web.xml (does it?) so I have to do manually. Could anyone assist me with getting the correct mappings?

Comment: Judging by that web.xml and that you call it "j2ee" you are copy/pasting this from REALLY old documentation / articles / tutorials. Use newer material please. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets.htm#BNAFD

Comment: which tomcat version are you using?

Comment: Hello, am using Tomcat 8

Comment: Are you packaging your application in a `TestGetServlet.war` file and deploying in the webapps/ folder?

Comment: No, am packaging in TestGet.war

Comment: If you are packaging it as TestGet then try to call /TestGet/servlet/TestGet.

Answer (score 0):

404 means that the page was not found, possibly because the url does not exist.

The `/servlet/TestGet` part you use for the servlet mapping in your url is correct. Your `web.xml` seems also correct.
Check if the application is named `TestGetServlet`.

Comment: the application's class name is TestGet

Comment: Have you been able to access any other page of the application?
I would add a quick index.html with a short message to just check if it works.

Comment: this is the only application on my server

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration and code seems correct. Perhaps the problem is in the `build.xml`.

Go to your tomcat installation\wtpwebapps(or webapps)\yourApp\WEB-INF and ensure that:

- Your `web.xml` is correct
- Exists the directory `WEB-INF\classes` and contains your compiled code (.class).

If you use eclipse, add a tomcat (`File` - `New` - `Server`) to deploy more easy and quickly